# Is there a default music editor/library that is used to display sheet music on the web?

Tags: music, html-editor, music-composing

I have found this one [abcjs](https://github.com/paulrosen/abcjs/blob/master/api.md), but I don't have enough information about this topic.

Requirements:

1. I want to use this with a markdown editor.
2. Musicians should know how to edit sheet music on it.
3. It is considered as default in the community.
4. Does anybody know about an important website such as Wikipedia or [Music Stack Exchange](https://music.stackexchange.com/) that uses this kind of editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Music.SE has been trying to push for [Lilypond](http://www.lilypond.org/) support which has many of the features you have requested.

There is a lot of external support for Lilypond [as shown by numerous third-party components](http://www.lilypond.org/easier-editing.html), and there's definitely been some interesting integration done with [MediaWiki where it not only displays the music, but also plays it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LilyPond#Collaboration_with_other_projects).

Here's a simple example:

```
\version "2.16.0"  % necessary for upgrading to future LilyPond versions.

\header{
  title = "A scale in LilyPond"
  subtitle = "For more information on using LilyPond, please see
http://lilypond.org/introduction.html"
}

\relative c' {
  c d e f g a b c
}
```

and the output:

[image]